# DATEDIFF Round off cutoff date hours SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datediff, hour

My client has this KTV hour rule all check out above 20 mins will be considered as additional 1 hour.

Example code below:

```
  declare @dateStart as datetime, @dateEnd as datetime

  set @dateStart = cast('3/2/2013 8:00:00 PM' as datetime)
  set @dateEnd   = cast('3/2/2013 9:20:02 pm' as datetime)

  SELECT DATEDIFF(hour, @dateStart, @dateEnd)
```

The code above logically returns 1:20 hours. In SQL server it will return 1 hour. How can I tweak this code to return as 2 hours?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `@dateStart` always exactly on the hour? What should the result be if the start was `7:59:59` and end was `9:00:01`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
declare @dateStart as datetime, @dateEnd as datetime

set @dateStart = cast('3/2/2013 8:00:00 PM' as datetime)
set @dateEnd   = cast('3/2/2013 9:20:02 pm' as datetime)

SELECT CEILING(CAST( DATEDIFF(minute, @dateStart, @dateEnd)as float) / 60)
```

More: [CEILING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189818.aspx)

Comment: @IswantoSan : Doesn't work if difference is less that 1:20. It still `ceils` it.

Comment: @IswantoSan: Bu that fails the spec; it rounds everything up, not just from minute 20 to 59 up.

Comment: @IswantoSan : First line of question `KTV hour rule, all check out above 20 mins will be considered as additional 1 hour.`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
  declare @dateStart as datetime, @dateEnd as datetime

  set @dateStart = cast('3/2/2013 8:00:00 PM' as datetime)
  set @dateEnd   = cast('3/2/2013 9:20:02 pm' as datetime)

  SELECT DATEDIFF(hour, @dateStart, @dateEnd) 
+
case 
when datediff(minute,@dateStart, @dateEnd)%60>=20 then 1
else 0
end
```

To be more precise you can also add seconds here.

Comment: +1, But why not: `datediff(minute,@dateStart, @dateEnd)%60 > 0`? - Edit: Nevermind, I didnt see the statement at top where the 20 minutes limit was...

Answer (score 0):

Add 40 minutes to the elapsed time, and truncate to the hour, as here:

```
  declare @dateStart as datetime, @dateEnd as datetime

  set @dateStart = cast('3/2/2013 8:00:00 PM' as datetime)
  set @dateEnd   = cast('3/2/2013 9:20:02 pm' as datetime)


  select Elapsed = datediff(hour, @dateStart, dateadd(minute,40,@dateEnd))
```

returns

```
Elapsed
-----------
2
```